# pyodbc ValueError: month must be in 1.. 12

Tags: python, centos, odbc, pyodbc

I have pyodbc installed in Windows10(host os) and CentOS docker image.
In Windows10, it is working as expected, however it throws an error on docker image.
`ValueError: month must be in 1..12`

```py
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=db2; UID=myid; PWD=mypwd')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from mydb.atable')
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Windows 10: host OS
python3.7.4
pyodbc4.0.27
CentOS7: docker image
python3.6.8
pyodbc4.0.30

This is my dockerfile,

```
FROM centos7

RUN yum -y update
RUN yum install -y python3
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install wheel
RUN yum install -y python36-devel
RUN yum install -y libevent-devel
RUN yum install -y gcc-c++
```

Do I miss installing any dev tools on centos?

Comment: I have the same problem on another Linux without docker. Same Python version, same pyodbc version. It also happened using pyodbc 3.0.10
Database: Sybase ASE, OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.8 (Maipo)
It began malfunctioning about two weeks ago.

Comment: @Johannes did you solve ?

Comment: I'm just in the process of preparing a pull request and creating a detailed issue report.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on another Linux without docker. Same Python version, same pyodbc version. It also happened using pyodbc 3.0.10.

Database: Sybase ASE, OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.8 (Maipo)

**If your resultset contains timestamps, try this:**

A colleague created this patch but wants to stay anonymous at the moment.
https://github.com/pucgenie/pyodbc/pull/1

Basically the driver is provided a pointer to a SQLLEN and then fills just 32 bits. pyodbc isn't able to detect that (-1) was meant instead of (2^32 -1). The patch adds an ugly exceptional handling for 0x00000000FFFFFFFF.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Johannes solution, reading through the code change allowed me explore the problem further.

In the ODBC driver, you have a choice of sqllen4 or sqllen8 driver.  I found that selecting the sqllen8 driver in /etc/odbcinst.ini made the problem go away.

There is some documentation here on the matter: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20116.1570/html/aseodbc/aseodbc5.htm

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1034 5185504 Apr  8 09:23 libsapcrypto.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1034 5413262 Apr  8 09:23 libsapssfs.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1034  499679 Apr  8 09:23 libslcryptokernel.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1034     166 Apr  8 09:23 libslcryptokernel.so.sha256
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1034 3645535 Apr  8 08:16 libsybdrvodb-sqllen4.so  # <- don't use this one
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1034 3454884 Apr  9 03:30 libsybdrvodb-sqllen4.so.fbo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1034 3655680 Apr  8 09:23 libsybdrvodb-sqllen8.so  # <- use this one
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1034      25 Aug  7 04:44 libsybdrvodb.so -> ./libsybdrvodb-sqllen4.so
drwxrwxr-x 5 1000 1034    4096 Aug  7 04:44 locales
```